# EPPlus: cannot calculate simple formula : #VALUE! error

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, formula, epplus

I really don't understand why my (quite simple!) formula won't get calculated:

```
        var logfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\EpplusLogFile.txt");
        sheet.Workbook.FormulaParserManager.AttachLogger(logfile);
        var mycell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
        mycell.Formula = "1+1";
        mycell.Calculate();
        Console.WriteLine($"{mycell.Address} {mycell.Formula} {mycell.Value}");
        sheet.Workbook.FormulaParserManager.DetachLogger();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

1. Console displays: `A1 1+1 #VALUE!`
2. Log file is not created (but no exception is raised)

I'm using EPPlus 5.8.5

Additionally:

```
        var cell1 = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
        cell1.Value = 999;
        var cell2 = sheet.Cells[1, 2];
        cell2.Formula = "A1";
        cell2.Calculate();
        Console.WriteLine($"{cell2.Address} {cell2.Formula} {cell2.Value}");
```

Console displays: `B1 A1 999` as it's supposed to.
But:

```
        var cell1 = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
        cell1.Value = 999;
        var cell2 = sheet.Cells[1, 2];
        cell2.Formula = "A1+1";
        cell2.Calculate();
        Console.WriteLine($"{cell2.Address} {cell2.Formula} {cell2.Value}");
```

And console displays: `B1 A1+1 #VALUE!`

To me, this makes no sense.

Comment: Probably a silly tip, but did you try to use `=1+1` as formula?

Comment: I've never used EPPlus, but when I've used the straight-up OpenXML SDK, the "OpenXML Productivity Tool" is a extremely handy for stuff like that.  Microsoft has hidden it (issues with SHA-1 hashes).  You can find it here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5